# Streaming website data into Excel with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, web, scrape

A website provides streaming stock quotes via a browser over HTTPS connection. This is done by the server sending a POST HTTP header and updating its body with the new quotes. The DOM is then updated and this then translates into visual updates. I want to get these quotes, preferrably streaming as well, into Excel. I may use only VBA, .NET framwork, and firefox add-ons.

I am stuck over how to do it. I am limited to VBA and .NET and Firefox add-ons. What libraries, objects, firefox add-ons would you advise me to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need FireFox. You can either query data from VBA (good example is on [Mr Excel forum](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/showthread.php?t=452455)) or .NET (another set of examples on [Wilmott forum](http://www.wilmott.com/messageview.cfm?catid=10&threadid=25730&FTVAR_MSGDBTABLE=)). To refresh the data you can use Excel timer (Application.OnTime) or have infinitive loop. If you would like to refresh a number of cells independently, you may want to utilise RDT function which is very useful in such case ([MS Excel Help](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/rtd-function-HP010342864.aspx)).

Comment: Juliusz,

The data is streaming, there are no queries involved. Also the data gets updated multiple times per second as it is truly real time stock data. This stream of data is established by the server sending a POST HTTP header and keeping it alive. Then it sends <script>updatePrices(122,14.55)</script> to the body of the header. So the javascript function updatePrices is called and it changes the values. If I use Firebug to look at headers, there are multiple script tags arriving per second. 

The links you gave me are not what I want to do, though of course  thanks for your time!

Comment: In similar situation where quotes were sent via messaging backbone, we used RTD function and RTD Server ([How to create a RealTimeData server for Excel](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/285339)). The server would be responsible for processing the quotes and can be written in VB.NET/C# utilising .Net framework, which usually helps.